# How to get the signature scheme for an apk,V1 or V2？

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature

According to the file structure of apk based on different signature methods，**V1 only**，**both V1 and V2**，**V2 only**，I found that there is a distinct difference under the **META-INF** folder.
If an apk was signed by V2 Only,there are not any important information under the the **META-INF** folder.If an apk was signed by V1 Only or both V1 and V2, there is a file named **CERT.SF**,if you dont know this file,read it [signed JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signed_JAR_File).But the **CERT.SF** file that contains both the V1 and the V2 signature will have a special primary property named **X-Android-APK-Signed**.
But This method is very time consuming，you have to decompress the APK,then judge according to the **CERT.SF**.I looked at the relevant information, but there was no easy way to do it without decompress.
**V1 only**
[image]
**Both V1 and V2**
[image]
**V2 only**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most package formats based on .zip, there is not need to decompress the APK in one go; the files inside have been compressed separately.

Comment: Thanks for answer,you are right,and  I found a [project](https://github.com/ltlovezh/ApkChannelPackage) on GitHub and I I made a contribution to this piece on the dev branch of this project.